# fail create ext4 filesystem on micro sd card

Tags: partitioning, mount, gparted, sd-card

I have a micro SD card that is plugged into an SD adapter.
Using gparted, I create an ext4 partition and formatted to ext3. When the process is complete, I get a warning icon assoc with that partition entry and clicking on it shows the message shown below.

```
<i>Filesystem volume name:   <none>
Last mounted on:          <not available>
Filesystem UUID:          25928fdc-c49c-4782-9b0c-97fa557aa323
Filesystem magic number:  0xEF53
Filesystem revision #:    1 (dynamic)
Filesystem features:      has_journal ext_attr resize_inode dir_index filetype extent flex_bg sparse_super large_file huge_file uninit_bg dir_nlink extra_isize
Filesystem flags:         signed_directory_hash 
Default mount options:    user_xattr acl
Filesystem state:         clean
Errors behavior:          Continue
Filesystem OS type:       Linux
Inode count:              2048000
Block count:              8191744
Reserved block count:     409587
Free blocks:              8018170
Free inodes:              2047989
First block:              0
Block size:               4096
Fragment size:            4096
Reserved GDT blocks:      1022
Blocks per group:         32768
Fragments per group:      32768
Inodes per group:         8192
Inode blocks per group:   512
Flex block group size:    16
Filesystem created:       Sun Jun 24 06:01:00 2018
Last mount time:          n/a
Last write time:          Sun Jun 24 06:01:00 2018
Mount count:              0
Maximum mount count:      -1
Last checked:             Sun Jun 24 06:01:00 2018
Check interval:           0 (<none>)
Lifetime writes:          132 MB
Reserved blocks uid:      0 (user root)
Reserved blocks gid:      0 (group root)
First inode:              11
Inode size:           256
Required extra isize:     28
Desired extra isize:      28
Journal inode:            8
Default directory hash:   half_md4
Directory Hash Seed:      2ba00213-aba2-49cc-8134-0ba0dfbc89df
Journal backup:           inode blocks</i>

<i>dumpe2fs 1.42.13 (17-May-2015)
Journal superblock magic number invalid!</i>

<i>Unable to read the contents of this file system!
Because of this, some operations may be unavailable.
The cause might be a missing software package.
The following list of software packages is required for ext4 file system support:  e2fsprogs v1.41+.</i>
```

When I remove and insert it into the system, I get a dialogbox with the message:

```
Error mounting /dev/mmcblk0p1 at /media/wt/25928fdc-c49c-4782-9b0c-97fa557aa323: Command-line `mount -t "ext4" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid" "/dev/mmcblk0p1" "/media/wt/25928fdc-c49c-4782-9b0c-97fa557aa323"' exited with non-zero exit status 32: mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/mmcblk0p1,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error

       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail or so.
```

I also tried using fdisk to create DOS partition table and then proceeded to create a linux partition and then use mkfs.ext4 to create the ext4 filesystem. It also shows the same dialogbox with the message show above when I insert the sd card into the system.

```
$ sudo fdisk /dev/mmcblk0
-delete previous partition table
-create new DOS partition
-create new partition
$ sudo mkfs.ext4 /dev/mmcblk0p1
```

**Update 2018/06/26:**

I am using a no-name class 10 32GB microSD card. I have also used a class 10 Sandisk Ultra 32GB HC I. They both gave me the same issue.
I should note that configuring the microSD to fat32 and ext2 filesystems was ok. It fails for ext3 and ext4.

Here are the steps used to create partition and ext4 filesystem using console:

$ sudo fdisk /dev/mmcblk0

```
Welcome to fdisk (util-linux 2.27.1).
Changes will remain in memory only, until you decide to write them.
Be careful before using the write command.

Command (m for help): o
Created a new DOS disklabel with disk identifier 0xd01d80de.

Command (m for help): n
Partition type
   p   primary (0 primary, 0 extended, 4 free)
   e   extended (container for logical partitions)
Select (default p): p
Partition number (1-4, default 1): 
First sector (2048-65535999, default 2048): 
Last sector, +sectors or +size{K,M,G,T,P} (2048-65535999, default 65535999): 

Created a new partition 1 of type 'Linux' and of size 31.3 GiB.

Command (m for help): p
Disk /dev/mmcblk0: 31.3 GiB, 33554432000 bytes, 65536000 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xd01d80de

Device         Boot Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/mmcblk0p1       2048 65535999 65533952 31.3G 83 Linux

Command (m for help): a
Selected partition 1
The bootable flag on partition 1 is enabled now.

Command (m for help): p
Disk /dev/mmcblk0: 31.3 GiB, 33554432000 bytes, 65536000 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xd01d80de

Device         Boot Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/mmcblk0p1 *     2048 65535999 65533952 31.3G 83 Linux

Command (m for help): w
The partition table has been altered.
Calling ioctl() to re-read partition table.
Syncing disks.
```

$ sudo mkfs.ext4 /dev/mmcblk0p1

```
mke2fs 1.42.13 (17-May-2015)
/dev/mmcblk0p1 contains a ext4 file system
    created on Wed Jun 27 00:29:23 2018
Proceed anyway? (y,n) y
Creating filesystem with 8191744 4k blocks and 2048000 inodes
Filesystem UUID: f58e93c1-b72d-42b0-bc67-2a73beaeb1dc
Superblock backups stored on blocks: 
    32768, 98304, 163840, 229376, 294912, 819200, 884736, 1605632, 2654208, 
    4096000, 7962624

Allocating group tables: done
Writing inode tables: done
Creating journal (32768 blocks): done
Writing superblocks and filesystem accounting information: done
```

When sdcard is inserted into slot, a dialogbox is shown on my desktop with the following error message:

```
Error mounting /dev/mmcblk0p1 at /media/wt/f58e93c1-b72d-42b0-bc67-2a73beaeb1dc: Command-line `mount -t "ext4" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid" "/dev/mmcblk0p1" "/media/wt/f58e93c1-b72d-42b0-bc67-2a73beaeb1dc"' exited with non-zero exit status 32: mount: /dev/mmcblk0p1 is write-protected, mounting read-only
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/mmcblk0p1,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error

       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail or so.
```

$ dmesg|tail

```
...
[38477.068800] mmc0: new high speed SDHC card at address 0001
[38477.069303] mmcblk0: mmc0:0001 USB D 31.3 GiB (ro)
[38477.071263]  mmcblk0: p1
[38477.564510] JBD2: no valid journal superblock found
[38477.564516] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p1): error loading journal
```

Comment: Hi. Try to eject/reinsert the sd after each single operation. IE: Delete table, eject. Create new table, eject... That said, you should know that a dead sd becomes non-writeable

Comment: Did `mkfs` give any errors?

Comment: I have updated the description, does it give any insight?Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: The following link may help you to analyze the problem, and if you are lucky, to solve it. [Can't format my usb drive. I have already tried with mkdosfs and gparted](https://askubuntu.com/questions/144852/cant-format-my-usb-drive-i-have-already-tried-with-mkdosfs-and-gparted/933035#933035)